# How to install Linux on VMware with Windows 7 Premium Host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, vmware, vmware-tools

I have an ASUS laptop with 6 GB RAM, Windows 7 64-Bit m/c. I followed this to install VMware, Linux:

[Installing VM (with Ubuntu + RVM + Ruby + Rails) on my Windows 7 system](http://niranjansarade.blogspot.in/2012/02/installing-vmwith-ubuntu-rvm-ruby-rails.html)

VMware (which has been installed successfully) keeps saying that it's installing VMware tools.

I even went through RubyInstaller. I am bit confused as to what steps I should follow because I want to get VWware enabled with Linux so that I can just mount my project and start using it to create ROR apps on my laptop.

Comment: You don't strictly need Linux to use Ruby on Rails... have you tried RailsInstaller for Windows?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,i even have one on windows which i control from CMD,but i need ROR on linux platform as using windows is unfamiliar for me....

Comment: What about this option: Boot into Linux? Also, VMWare Tools is not strictly required for Linux to work.

Comment: I would also suggest to install Linux (perhaps in dual boot with Windows) on your laptop, and to take time (hours or days) to learn Linux....

Comment: i forget to mention that i have been working on linux for more than a year....i want to make use of VMware...any suggestions.???

Answer (score 0):

After googling, I got the answer.

This excellent article from Ryan Bigg [how to get started using ruby-rvm-rails-ubuntu](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/) shows detailed steps and guides you to get the correct configurations.

Comment: If you register your Super User account using the same OpenID you use on Stack Overflow you should regain ownership of the question.